# Remove $ before a number

Tags: r

I'm new to R and have a fairly simple question.  I am working with a data frame and want to convert one of the columns from a character to numeric.  The issue I am running into is that it represents a price and is currently formatted as $7 for 7 dollars.  I want to make this 7.  When i use `as.numeric` it returns all `NA`s.  I also tried `gsub("$","", cookies$Price)`, but the `$` isn't dropping off.

Comment: `$` is a special regex character, you need to escape it as `\\$`

Comment: That and use `fixed=TRUE` if you do not want any meta-characters applied.

Comment: As @Hrbrmstr said; `gsub("\\$","", cookies$Price)` would do the trick for your code

Comment: Or `gsub("[$]", "", cookies$Price)`

Comment: Thanks for the help. This worked.  I appreciate it.